# How to define an initial image preloaded in filepond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepond

I'm doing a laravel view of the editing of a record, which has an image associated with it, and I need it to appear preloaded inside the input file, so that if you submit, the same image is sent, or if you want to change it.

```
 // Turn input element into a pond
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginFileEncode,
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize
);
var imagen = '{{ trim($marca->imagen_asociada) }}'
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        load: imagen.replace('/images/button/','')
    }
});
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement,{
    files: [
        {
            source: '{{ public_path().'/resources'.trim($marca->imagen_asociada) }}',
            options: {
                type: 'local',

                // mock file information
                file: {
                    name: imagen.replace('/images/button/',''),
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Now it shows like this

[image]

But I should show in this way
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, fixed it by this:

```
/*FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        load: imagen.replace('/images/button/','')
    }
}); Remove this.*/
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement,{
    files: [
        {
            source: '{{ public_path().'/resources'.trim($marca->imagen_asociada) }}',
            /*options: {
                type: 'local',

                // mock file information
                file: {
                    name: imagen.replace('/images/button/',''),
                }
            } - Remove this options {} dictionary */
        }
    ]
});
```

According to documentation [Under Setting Initial Files](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files)

Answer (score 0):

If you mock the file data FilePond won't load the actual file and the image preview plugin won't have any data to show the file.

Make sure your `server.load` endpoint returns a file object.